# soapUI: looking for xpath expression to capture specific value from response when multiple result entities return and its order may vary

Tags: xpath, soapui

I have a API call which may return more than 1 result entities. The order of the result entities may vary. How do I capture say executionID of a specific entity whose "state" (another field in entity) is "INPROGRESS". Is there a solution using something like xpath expression for this?
here is the sample response --

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
  <bns:queryResponse xmlns:bns="http://api.xyz.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <bns:results numberOfResults="3">
        <bns:result xsi:type="bns:ExecutionRecord">
           <bns:executionId>execution1-5b041417-691b-4f56-b1d4-2b2d35cb5353</bns:executionId>
           <bns:account>account1</bns:account>
           <bns:executionTime>2015-06-24T16:31:25Z</bns:executionTime>
           <bns:status>ERROR</bns:status>
           </bns:result>
        <bns:result xsi:type="bns:ExecutionRecord">
           <bns:executionId>execution2-5b041417-691b-4f56-b1d4-2b2d35cb5353</bns:executionId>
           <bns:account>account1</bns:account>
           <bns:executionTime>2015-06-24T16:31:25Z</bns:executionTime>
           <bns:status>INPROGRESS</bns:status>
           </bns:result>
        </bns:result>
        <bns:result xsi:type="bns:ExecutionRecord">
           <bns:executionId>execution3-5b041417-691b-4f56-b1d4-2b2d35cb5353</bns:executionId>
           <bns:account>account1</bns:account>
           <bns:executionTime>2015-06-24T16:31:25Z</bns:executionTime>
           <bns:status>ERROR</bns:status>
           </bns:result>
        </bns:result>
       </bns:results>
  </bns:queryResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Of course! If you provide sample response, and what exactly you want, we might even be able to help you. See [ask].

Comment: Please find the sample response attached for reference

Comment: for starter the xmls is invalid...  you close result two times for the second record... and on the third record too.. forget it that response xpath, that response is invalid xml...

Comment: well, I just took out the part that was unnecessary and while doing that I may have missed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned, your XML sample is broken. But there is enough there that you should be able to use something like the following XPath:

```
//*:status[text()='INPROGRESS']/preceding-sibling::*:executionId/text()
```

This uses "axis" to first find the status node with your text, and then its sibling executionId node.

Alternatively, something like this should work too:

```
//*:result[*:status[text()='INPROGRESS']]/*:executionId/text()
```

This just finds the result node, which contains your status node, and returns that executionId.

Additional information on XPath can be [found here](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html).

Comment: Thank you for quick response-- //bns:queryResponse[1]/bns:results[1]/bns:result[*:status[., 'INPROGRESS']]/*:executionId      (this format seem to be grabbing the first available execution ID all the time irrespective of its status)

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Not sure how your XPath relates to the XPaths that I provided in my answer.

Comment: I used your second suggested format. In the first part i could not understand how to format preceding-sibling part

Comment: it only grabs the id from 1st entity all the time, so ignores the status seems

Comment: I corrected my code. Also, what do you mean "i could not understand how to format preceding-sibling"? What I posted is literal.

Comment: Awesome.. thank you so much for the help. both the solutions above worked and could solve a big automation issue for me. Thanks!!